# Calculating the Big-o notation (python)

Tags: python

In my recent class of computer science we got the following code (python):

```
def BigO_2(n): 
   L=[]
   for i in range(n):
       for j in range(n):
           L.append(i*j)
   for i in range(n)
```

We were asked what is the time complexity of the code. For some reason the answer was O(n^3). As far as I understand it, it is a O(n^2) complexity that *can* be a O(n^3), means that O(n^2) is also the right answer. An explanation would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Could you put the rest of the code as well, it looks missing

Comment: For me it looks like O(n^2 + n) which is basically O(n^2)

Comment: What you've posted would simply error, so it isn't O anything.

Comment: The code was given exactly that way (probably a part of a program or smthing), we dont test if the code works (obviously it is not) so I assume the only addition to this is just a return of the list (only for debugging purposes). So, assuming the code *is* running (there is some kind of return in the end of the function), what is the big-o notation? thanks for the asnwers so far

Answer (score 1):

The code looks missing
but if it's not missing so here is my answer:

```
for i in range(n):
   for j in range(n):
       L.append(i*j)
```

This would be O(n^2)
Because the nested loop that contains two loops each O(n)

```
   for i in range(n)
```

And this one is O(n)

So it's O(n^2+n)
Which equals to O(n^2)